# How/why does the name field override groupid

Tags: maven

I have this in a library pom.xml file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.oresoftware</groupId>
<artifactId>async.0.1</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1.101</version>
<name>org.ores.async.Asyncc</name>
<url>https://github.com/ORESoftware/async.java</url>
```

when I import the library in another project, I use:

```
import org.ores.async.Asyncc;
```

whereas this does not resolve:

```
import com.oresoftware.async.Asyncc;
```

as an aside, I also tried to pull some trick where I would publish different minor versions to do a different namespace to prevent version conflicts:

```
 <artifactId>async.0.1</artifactId>
```

Maven let me do this (`mvn install` succeeds), but I suspect it wouldn't work in actuality, because I can't import:

import com.oresoftware.async.0.1.Asyncc;

[image]

Comment: "when I import the library in another project, I use:`import org.ores.async.Asyncc;`" ..confusing! why would you do that? (import some "maven project name") ..ok: (unfortunately) also a class resides there with the exact name `org.ores.async.Asyncc` ...but then `import com.oresoftware.asynnc.0.1....` is not a valid package name (and no such class exists) (packages may not start with numbers...) ..remove that import (line 2), and everything should be "fine".

Comment: I think it's because my project/folder structure actually uses `org.ores.async.Asyncc`, instead of using `com.oresoftware.async.Asyncc`....weird that Maven lets you do that. I would think your project structure would have to match the groupid etc.

Comment: no, not obligatory! (this is default(&"nice feature") by most "archetypes") BUT: "using numbers in your `artifactId`" (like a version) - is a "smell"!

Comment: The package names and the groupId should match but of course not really need but it's better to do (there are exceptions of that)...Having an artifactId which contains `.` is not only a smell it's simply wrong and if we are talking about JDK9+ modules it is simply forbidden... Apart from that I don't understand the need for such numbers in an artifactId which look like a version? For such purposes the version does exist...